# Passing arguments with spaces and quotes to a script (without quoting everything)

Tags: shell-script, quoting, function, arguments, whitespace

The following works great on the command-line:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.m4a -metadata 'title=Spaces and $pecial char'\''s' output.m4a
```

How do I parameterize this command and use it in a script/function? I would like to add multiple metadata tags like this:

```
$ set-tags.sh -metadata 'tag1=a b c' -metadata 'tag2=1 2 3'
```

**update:**

I simplified my question a little too much. I actually want to call a script that calls a script with with the parameterized command in it.

**This is my exact use case:**

This function converts files to audio-book format (defined in .profile):

```
# snippet of .profile
convert_to_m4b () {
    FILE="$1"
    BASENAME=${FILE%.*}; shift

    ffmpeg -i "$FILE" -vn -ac 1 -ar 22050 -b:a 32k "$@" tmp.m4a &&
    mv tmp.m4a "$BASENAME.m4b"
}; export -f convert_to_m4b
```

Function convert_to_m4b is called from download-and-convert.sh:

```
#/bin/sh
 MP3_URL=$1; shift
FILENAME=$1; shift

if [ ! -f "${FILENAME}.mp3" ]; then
    curl --location --output "${FILENAME}.mp3" "$MP3_URL"
fi

convert_to_m4b "${FILENAME}.mp3" "$@"
```

Download-and-convert.sh is called from process-all.sh:

```
#/bin/sh
download-and-convert.sh http://1.mp3 'file 1' -metadata 'title=title 1' -metadata 'album=album 1'
download-and-convert.sh http://2.mp3 'file 2' -metadata 'title=title 2' -metadata 'album=album 2'
...
...
download-and-convert.sh http://3.mp3 'file N' -metadata 'title=title N' -metadata 'album=album N'
```

I get this error from ffmpeg:

```
[NULL @ 00000000028fafa0] Unable to find a suitable output format for ''@''
'@': Invalid argument
```

`"$@"` works if I inline convert_to_m4b in download-and-convert.sh instead of calling the function.

---

The following does not work because the quotes are lost, causing arguments with spaces to be incorrectly split up:

```
#/bin/sh
ffmpeg -i input.m4a $@ output.m4a
```

I have tried various methods of [quoting the `$@`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34515468/117030), but this ends up quoting `'-metadata'` as well, so the command line argument is not properly recognized.

I guess I would like to only surround each argument with quotes if that argument was quoted to begin with. This seems difficult to do because bash strips the quotes before being passing arguments to the script/function.

Or is there a better method of relaying the `-metadata` arguments? (like environment variables or files)

Comment: Have some faith man, `ffmpeg -i input.m4a "$@" output.m4a` does what you want. :) Also, `-metadata "title=It's got spaces"` is easier to write than `-metadata 'title=It'\''s got spaces'`.

Comment: @Satō please turn that into an answer, it’s much better than the current answers :-/.

Comment: @SatōKatsura: I actually have one additional level of indirection that prevents "$@" from working. Will update question...

Comment: The solution is still `"$@"`.  Change the upper layer scripts to take this into account, not the other way around.  Unquoted `$@` is almost never what you want (it certainly isn't here).

Comment: @SatōKatsura: Can you explain how to change the upper layer scripts? I tried changing the upper layer scripts to "$@" as well, but I got an error where $@ did not seem to be expanded. BTW I am using single quotes so special charactes like '$' do not get expanded if they are part of the metadata.

Comment: I can't "explain" anything as long as you don't show exactly what you're trying to do and why `"$@"` doesn't work. _shrug_

Comment: @SatōKatsura: I added my exact use case, along with the ffmpeg error I get when I double quote all instances of `$@`

Comment: @SatōKatsura: Sorry, I was trying to provide the minimal information required and keep things understandable. I think I added everything, now.

Comment: The argument expansion seems to work fine.  Replace `ffmpeg` with `printf '|%s|\n'` and see what this gives. BTW: `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#/bin/sh`.  This may be part of your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65162/discussion-between-leftium-and-sat-katsura).

Comment: Sorry, my browser doesn't work with this site's chat. _shrug_

Comment: @SatōKatsura: that's why I don't usually move the comments to chat. I got your suggestion to work, and I was just thanking you ;). I'm not sure what I missed before, though... starting working when I swapped ffmpeg w/ printf (and back again because the outputs were exactly the same)

Comment: This happens typically because of unbalanced / misplaced quotes on the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"$@"` does exactly what you want provided that you use it consistently.  Here's a little experiment for you:

- `script1.sh`:

  ```
  #! /bin/sh
  ./script2.sh "$@"
  ```
- `script2.sh`:

  ```
  #! /bin/sh
  ./script3.sh "$@"
  ```
- `script3.sh`:

  ```
  #! /bin/sh
  printf '|%s|\n' "$@"
  ```

With this the arguments stay unmolested all the way down:

```
$ ./script1.sh -i input.m4a -metadata "title=Spaces and \$pecial char's" output.m4a
|-i|
|input.m4a|
|-metadata|
|title=Spaces and $pecial char's|
|output.m4a|
```